# Can someone tell me how I can make my Windows Server Web 2008 R2 like Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using Windows web server 2008 R2. Every time I have open my computer and they have show me

"Preparing your computer...."
"create ...."

I want to stop it. it's take more time to load. Every time I boot and I see this kind of stuff. This is not happen in Windows 7.

Can someone tell me? I have no idea how to stop it.

Comment: Too complicated to post how to do it, [see this website for instructions and tools.](http://www.win2008r2workstation.com/) .